# Chrome Extension (content script) - Adding button at specific position in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I'm creating a Chrome Extension that scans your current page for phonenumbers, and after each phonenumber found, a Click-To-Call button has to be created.

Current code:

```
var number = foobar,
    queue = [document.body],
    curr;

while (curr = queue.pop()) {
    if (!curr.textContent.match(number)) continue;
    for (var i = 0; i < curr.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        switch (curr.childNodes[i].nodeType) {
            case Node.TEXT_NODE :
                var match = curr.childNodes[i].textContent.match(number);
                if (match) {
                    if(!curr.innerHTML.includes("fa-phone-square")) {
                        var $call_button = $('<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true" id="'+ match +'"></i>').click(call);
                        $(curr).append($call_button);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE :
                queue.push(curr.childNodes[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works, but the problem is that the Click-To-Call button is now placed at the end of whatever element the phonenumber was found in, which can result in some weird interactions.

Example:

```
Name: John Doe
Phone: 1234567890
Mail: example@example.com [button]
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
Name: John Doe
Phone: 1234567890 [button]
Mail: example@example.com
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$(curr).append($call_button);
```

to

```
$(curr.childNodes[i]).after($call_button);
```